# RDP connection error : freerdp_set_last_error ERRCONNECT_SECURITY_NEGO_CONNECT_FAILED

Tags: remmina

During a session setup from Ubuntu to windows 7 I got this error
I delete .remmina folder without success

Answer (score 0):

The solution to solve this was to delete the .config/freerdp/ content